# how to check key's value in a dictionary with a default value

Tags: python

how can I understand that the key and value is not in the dictionary ? If it is possible, I will use as if new value is not in the dictionary add it in. Example

```
d = {1:"k", 2:"l"}
```

if 3 is not in the list, the code should understand and put it is a new item to dictionary with null value

```
d = {1:"k", 2:"l", 3:"null"}
```

Comment: Using a string `"null"` as a *null value* is a terrible idea. Use `None` (or just don't have the value there. You can simply catch the exception when you try and access it).

Comment: what do You men "key and value is not in the dictionary"? key not in dictionary or even situation when key is in dictionary but value differs is the case?

Comment: @oleg read what you wrote. Give answer to yourself. do not bother me. IDIOAT

Answer (score 7):

You can use `dict.setdefault`:

```
d.setdefault(3,"null")
```

demo:

```
>>> d = {1:"k", 2:"l"}
>>> d.setdefault(3,"null")    # if key is found then return the value else
                              # set the new key and return the new value  
'null'                     
>>> d
{1: 'k', 2: 'l', 3: 'null'}
```

**help** on `dict.setdefault`:

```
>>> dict.setdefault?
Type:       method_descriptor
String Form:<method 'setdefault' of 'dict' objects>
Namespace:  Python builtin
Docstring:  D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using a default dict / default values, you can achieve this with:

```
if 3 not in d:
    d[3] = None # or "null"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `in` operator.

```
>>> d = {1:"k", 2:"l"}
>>> 1 in d
True
>>> 2 in d
True
>>> 3 in d
False
>>> if not 3 in d:
...     d[3] = "null"
...
>>> d
{1: 'k', 2: 'l', 3: 'null'}
>>>
```

Comment: `3 not in d` looks nicer

Comment: @jamylak, agreed. It just that I use `not condition` style always.

Comment: So you would always write `not (x == y)` over `x != y`?

Comment: @Eric, lol no. What I meant is instead of writing `condition == False` I write `not condition`. Here `3 in d` is the condition. I will write `x == y` :-).

Comment: @taskinoor: I really don't see any difference between `in/not in` and `==/!=`. Any argument you make for one set can be applied to the other.

Comment: @Eric, I am not making argument that one style is better/worse than another. Please don't get me wrong. What I said is that it is rather my personal habit/choice to write in this way (which does not necessarily mean that is the best). Please see my first comment, I agreed to jamylak that `3 not in d` looks nicer.

Answer (score 0):

you should understand that there is two questions
1. how to check if key existed in a hash
2. how to check a key's value in a hash

a1.

```
key in hash
```

a2.

```
hash[key]
```